# Fastest way to update an attribute in all products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, products-management

I'm trying to update the price to a lot of products (more than 10.000). The way I am doing that right now is extremely time-consuming. Which is the best way to loop through all the products and update most of them?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/hide-products-with-a-zero-price

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hi Magento  provide an attribute by below code

```
$product->setAttributeCode($newValue)
$ProductObject->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attribute_Code');
```

### Example:

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
// below code use for time format 
$product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');
```

### Using Product Collection:

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
    // below code use for time format 
    $product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');


}
```

Comment: This is super fast! I've tried `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_api')->update();` and `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()`. product_api took 1.7 seconds on avg and product_action took 1.0 seconds on avg. however, `$product->getResource()->saveAttribute()` took on avg 0.04 Seconds on avg. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything similar to this method that can update attributes at a certain store level?

Comment: Thx @Amit Bera -- 1 question remaining ;) is there also a way to save multiple attributes in 1 go? Of would one have to loop around the `$product->getResource()->saveAttribute` action. THX!!

Comment: @amit bera, pls look into this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201757/created-a-custom-module-custom-admin-form   what should i do ??

Comment: @amit: I need how can i bulk change website (update attribute in multi-store)

Comment: Agreed, this is much faster than $product->save(). Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Write an SQL Query.

Second best way (and the one I recommend): `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Action::updateAttributes`

Code example by u_maxx:

```
$allProductIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$attributeCode = 'some_eav_attribute';
$attributeValue = NULL;
$attrData = array( $attributeCode => $attributeValue );
$storeId = 0;
// no reindex:<
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/resource_product_action')->updateAttributes($allPro‌​ductIds, $attrData, $storeId);
// reindex:
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($allPro‌​ductIds, $attrData, $storeId);
```

> How would this work with multiselect values? Does it 'add' the value or overwrite other pre-selected values

Multiselects are normally saved as comma seperated integers, like `27,42,4711`. Therefore if you change the value to say `1`, the other values are lost. But what you can do is something like `CONCAT(value, ',1')` means adding the new value to the end, seperated by a comma. I **think** even if you add a value two times, this is no problem, because Magento filters it the next time the item is saved and ignores the second value.

Comment: This will only update 1k rows at a time, not as quick: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Action.php#L79

Comment: When I understand the code correctly it writes every 1000 rows, but it updates all in a row.

Comment: Not sure either, but just from a quick poke around, upvote for the pointing out the method however, wasn't aware of it either.

Comment: Thank you @FabianBlechschmidt! Here is my code example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/u-maxx/49ba617d9400c1090b99a3551647f492)): `<?php 
 $allProductIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
 $attributeCode = 'some_eav_attribute';
 $attributeValue = NULL;
 $attrData = array(
  $attributeCode => $attributeValue
 );
 $storeId = 0;
 Mage::getSingleton('catalog/resource_product_action')->updateAttributes($allProductIds, $attrData, $storeId);
`

Comment: Just to be clear. This is great for updating multiple! products to the same attribute=>value pair -- I dont see how one could do the query in 1 go updating multiple! products with different  attribute=>value data. Is that correct? THX

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't reindex the products, so you may not see changes in the frontend and just see them in the admin panel.  To also reindex after update you can change `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/resource_product_action')` to `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')` with the exact same parameters mentioned above.

Comment: I need how can i bulk change website (update attribute in multi-store)

Comment: Hello @FabianBlechschmidt , I have tried above code it works good. but only i have issue is store_id. I wan to change attribute of specific store. Above code is update attribute of all store. can you give me solution for it?

Comment: If you change the storeId to the appropriate ID of the one store, still everything is changed? Then you found a bug ::(

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt How would this work with multiselect values? Does it 'add' the value or overwrite other pre-selected values ..

Comment: @snh_nl updated the answer. Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 5):

10k products, use SQL. EAV just muddies the waters. Per question is Fastest way.

Find attribute_id

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 4 and attribute_code = 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE'
```

Update with found `attribute_id` from above query.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 1 WHERE attribute_id = FOUND_ATTRIBUTE_ID
```

I suppose you could do a subselect with update but for simplicities sake two SQL queries is easiest to grasp.

**NOTE:** `entity_type_id = 4` is most always the product EAV entries. In case you are needing to mass update category or customer attributes this will differ as well as the table that is updated based on what type of attribute it is your updating. Also if you have multi-store setup be sure and note and condition `store_id`

Answer (score 3):

Further to Fabian's answer above, you can update multiple fields at a time. The example below has just 2 (in stock, stock status), but you can use as many as you want.

```
    $product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 2)) //only disabled 
        ->getAllIds();

    $attrData = [
        ['attribute_one' => 1],
        ['attribute_two' => 1]
    ];

    $storeId = 0;
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/resource_product_action')
       ->updateAttributes($product_ids, $attrData, $storeId);
```

Comment: So this is if you want to update all products tot he *same* attribute value - how could you adapt this to update say 3 products, all the same attribute, but with different values for the attribute? thx

Comment: See Amit Bera's answer above: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/43924/3433