# How to change a particular store's product prices?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I have different stores of different products. I want to change all products prices of particular store.
I have a code of it. But it takes so much time on save function because i have so many products.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->setStoreId($storeid)
                        ->load($productid)->setPrice($price);$product->save();
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quick update attribute using `->getResource()->saveAttribute('yourattriibutecode');`

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->setStoreId($storeid)
                        ->load($productid);

$product->setPrice($price)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
```

**Here you did not need save() which take lot of time;**

See at :

[Fastest way to update an attribute in all products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43917/fastest-way-to-update-an-attribute-in-all-products/43924#43924)

**[Edit:]**

```
$product->setSpecialPrice('');
$product->setSpecialFromDate();
$product->setSpecialToDate();

$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_price');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_to_date');
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, i successfully updated my all products prices through your code but now i have got another problem. Now my all products are showing regular and special prices. i want to set just one price for each product.

Comment: make special price null  using my code $product->setSpecialFromDate();$product->setSpecialToDate();$product->setSpecialPrice('');

Comment: and use >getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attibutecode'); every attribute

Comment: I am sorry Amit, i am new in Magento. can you please write me a just one fine code as you wrote first. I am confused now. Thank You

Comment: Amit I am getting error.Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

The fast solution for updating attributes is this

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_attribute')->updateAttributes(
    array($productId),
    array('price' => $price),
    $storeId
);
```

But in your case there is a catch. The price attribute scope can be global or website. You shouldn't change the price for a store view.
I'm not sure it even works, and even if it does, you will lose the value the next time you manually save a product because of the price attribute scope.