# Created a custom module (custom admin-form)

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

I have Created a custom module (custom form). But when i have seen user feedback from admin backend. There is no. of comments. 
Total no. of record is 350 in just 1 day. How can this possible ?

attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: These are all spam comment. you can remove all comments and add recaptch in your site. It will helpful for protecting unnecessary spam comments

Comment: Anyone guide me how can i integrate Custom Feedback Form Code Into Magento -  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/244255/57334