# If the price is 0 deactivate the product

Tags: magento-1.9

I want products that have a price of 0 to be deactivated.

How can I do this?

My store is on magento 1.9.3

Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/hide-products-with-a-zero-price Follow this

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the products with price zero if you want to stop showing them on frontend

[Hide products with a zero price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/hide-products-with-a-zero-price)

Follow this and upvote if helps